# Understanding the definition of row echelon form from Golan.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

The definition is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand what is $s(i)$ and how to know it, could anyone give me a numerical example to explain the definition,please?

Comment: $s\left(i\right)$ is just a dummy variable. He doesn't write $s$ because there is one such integer for each $i$, and you cannot call them all $s$; you have to put the $i$ somewhere to be able to distinguish them from one another. Most people would call them $s_i$ instead, but it's just a matter of notation.

Comment: This may help to clarify the definition:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355553/clarifications-on-row-echelon-form-and-reduced-row-echelon-form/3355604#3355604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for each row $i$,  all elements before a certain column $j=s(i)$ are $0$, and that the function $i\longmapsto j=s(i)$ is (strictly) increasing, i.e. the number of $0$s at the beginning of a row is increasing.

This condition is not satisfied in the counterexample they give, as $s(1)=1, s(2)=3, s(3)=3, s(4)=5$.

Comment: But how is $s(i) \leq  n+1?$ should not it be strictly less than $n+1$?

Comment: If $s(i)=n+1$, it means that you have a row of $0$s (so all further rows will be $0$ rows).

Comment: But $n$ is the number of columns not rows.

Comment: Oops! I thought this was a square matrix. However, $\mathcal M_{k\times n}$, in the usual conventions, denotes the set of matrices with $k$ rows and $n$ columns.

Comment: So what does it mean $s(i) = n +1 $ in this case?

Comment: It means what I wrote : the coefficients in row $i$  with column index  $\le n+1$ are $0$. As there's no column with index $n+1$, the condition on the column index is empty, and  it means that for all (real) columns, the coefficients in row $i$ are $0$. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

$s(i)$ is the position (column number) of the first nonzero entry in row $i$.  In the last matrix in your example $s(2) = s(3) = 3$.

If row $i$ is all $0$ then $s(i)=n+1$ even though there are only $n$ columns.

Comment: But how $s(i) \leq n+1$? is not it should be strictly less than $n+1$?